# Is there a way to manage passport-local profiles?

Tags: node.js, passport.js

I search a way to manage the local profiles in passportjs.

For exmaple i will have a list of all users that signed up and i willcan delete them and maybe activate them before they can use ther credentials after signing up.

Any ideas how to implement this, or are there already methods implemented which I can use?

I found nothing in the docs about user management.

Answer (score 1):

Dear this is total depend on you when any one register then you make an entry in the users table with activated flag = 0, and verified flag = 0.

By using admin UI you can activate and deactivate the user and when any one try to login then you may check the activate flag if 1 then login else say your account not verified.

Let me know if you have still any confusion.

Cheers!

Saran

Comment: Thank you Saran! I think about this in a simmilar way. In this way you implement roles, too? How you would send all the userdata to the admin page? With a socket-request? Or you would create a resource? For example a get route where you can check if the user role is admin and then handle it with angular resource on the client.